# What is the meaning, and origin, of the phrase "breaking windows with guineas"?

Tags: etymology, expressions, british-english

Regarding the phrase:

> Breaking windows with guineas

What is its meaning, and origin?

The 'guineas' part of it might mean more to the British audience on this site than the others.

Comment: FWIW, a guinea is a pound plus a shilling, for lots of excellent reasons...

Answer (score 7):

During the [Seven Years' War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Years%27_War) (1756-1763), Britain's ruinously expensive naval sorties against France were actually inflicting very little damage. In the specific case of the Sept 1757 [Raid on Rochefort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raid_on_Rochefort), British MP Henry Fox said it was like [breaking their windows with guineas](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mKVPUNbbeUEC&pg=PA268&dq=%22windows%20with%20guineas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sBLuTofEHO3c4QSl2c2cCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22windows%20with%20guineas%22&f=false) (i.e. - using and thus losing our most valuable coins as missiles, simply to break their glass windows).

It's really just a little-known quaint archaism. You're more likely to hear [Cut off your nose to spite your face](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_off_the_nose_to_spite_the_face) today.

Comment: I wouldn’t say that “cutting off your nose to spite your face” has quite the same meaning. “Throwing money down the drain” probably comes closer.

Answer (score 7):

To add to what FumbleFingers says: the phrase was coined by politician [Henry Fox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Fox,_1st_Baron_Holland) during the seven years' war to ridicule William Pitt and the British government that was spending quite a lot of money for very little results against the French.
I have found an [academic paper](http://abpo.revues.org/470) on the subject... it's in French.

I had never heard or read the phrase before. As to whether "cut off your nose to spite your face" really means the same I wonder. Couldn't we say "kill a fly with a sledgehammer"?

Comment: Fly with a sledgehammer means a disproportionate response, this is more that the response costs more than the damage. Closer is probably some US general's quote about Afghanistan - sending a million dollar missile to blow up a tent

Comment: I'm a bit surprised both you and @Brian Nixon in his comment to my answer don't think *"cut off your nose..."* has the same meaing. To my mind, the whole *point* of both expressions is that the aggressor is actually being damaged/losing money. *"Swatting a fly with a sledgehammer"* might be way over the top - but unless the fly is actually on your body at the time, you probably won't suffer unduly from the disproportionate action.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: They both express similar ideas, but I feel there's a subtle difference. _"Breaking windows with guineas"_ would (though I've never heard it "in the wild") suggest to me an attack so inefficient that it's costing you more than its effects are costing the target; the solution is either to stop or to find a cheaper way to do it. _"Cutting off your nose"_ is more about a situation where the action itself, no matter how well and cheaply carried out, will end up hurting yourself, much like (more specifically) _"sawing off the branch you're sitting on"_.

Comment: Many thanks to all, I think I get all the nuances now (concluding with Ilmari's balancing act) and will go back to the debate where it is being used

Comment: like (more specifically) "sawing off the branch you're sitting on". – Ilmari Karonen 3 hours ago... Did not see this part of it, which is far too general; I was thinking that this " the whole point of both expressions is that the aggressor is actually being damaged/losing money" from FumbleFingers was right on the ball?

Comment: @mgb --  "I'm not gonna fire a $2 million missile at a $10 empty tent and hit a camel in the butt." -- George W. Bush